# Increase Per-User Limit for Google API: Saving not possible, always error message "Your input was invalid"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics-api

I've the same problem as this user:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/mOOrYoTVWgo

"I am trying to increase the Per-User Limit from 1 requests/second/user to 10 requests/second/user for the Analytics API. I keep getting an error that says "Your input was invalid". I even tried updating without any changes and I keep getting the same error. It appears that there may be a bug with increasing Per-User Limits?"

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Google has fixed the bug, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue & found a workaround. I disabled all the other API services from the "Services" menu in my Google API Console. I turned "off" every other service except the Analytics API, then managed to update the per-user limit for Analytics API. After doing this, I then went back and re-activated the other API services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it, but in my case, it doesn't work, same error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue, limits may have changed on one of the apis you already are using.  Play around with some of your higher rate services and see if kicking them down allows you to update your limits.